# Images aligned next to a link move when I click that link

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

So basically, i have an image, a few links next to the image (on the same line), and another image to the right of those links (same line).

So the contents are like this: Left Image...Links... Right Image

The problem is that when I click on the links, the Right Image moves closer to the left towards the links. I have absolutely no idea why it does this, and I want to resolve this problem. An explanation for this phenomenon would be appreciated, thanks!

Also, JSFiddle displays it differently from what it looks like in my browser for some reason.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsujeeun/f56msebz/4/

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>The Broker</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="Real Estate Agent Toronto" name="keywords">
        <meta content="Homepage of a real estate agent in Toronto" name="description">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="Images/Remax80H.png">
            <div class="HBContainer"><a href="#"><span class="HeadButton">Home</span></a></div>
            <div class="HBContainer"><a href="#"><span class="HeadButton">Property Listings</span></a></div>
            <div class="HBContainer"><a href="#"><span class="HeadButton">Sitemap</span></a></div>
            <div class="HBContainer"><a href="#"><span class="HeadButton">Contact me</span></a></div>
            <div class="HBContainer"><a href="#"><span class="HeadButton">About me</span></a></div>
            <img src="Images/Profile80H.png">
        </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, #DAEDF6, white);
    border-bottom: 3px groove aqua;
}

.HBContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: 160%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.HeadButton {
    font-family: "Capsuula", sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: darkslategray;
    padding: 6%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


a .HeadButton:hover {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(115, 199, 191, 0.3);
}
img {
    padding: 0.5%;
}
```

Comment: if the problem can't be seen in your jsfiddle, keep working on the fiddle until it does reflect the problem.

Comment: When you click on the link or also when you hover over it? It could be the img's padding in % that is causing it to move, or the styles applied to the links when hovering.

Comment: only when I click on the link. hovering over it only changes the background color...